# Permission Set Cleanup - identifying duplicate permissions - AppExchange Product?

Tags: appexchange, permission-sets, duplicate-management

We have a 12 year old Salesforce org and we have not had the best governance around creating and assigning permission sets. We have numerous duplicate permissions - i.e. 'Transfer Record' System Permission spread across numerous permission sets.

I'm looking to install a package or steal some unmanaged code to help identify these redundancies. Believe it or not, I'm having a heck of a time finding an AppExchange package that does this - which seems odd to me as I would think it would be a common issue with aging SFDC orgs.

I was going to create an VF page that lists out permissions enabled for each permission set, [SELECT * FROM PermissionSet] and play around highlighting redundant areas for cleanup. However I wanted to post on here to see if anyone has tackled this issue before and had any suggestions.

I will of course post my page if we go live with this, so stay tuned. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea works and would be a quick turnaround in that SOQL would help you find the count of permission sets with the exposed fields available.

I'll put in a +1 to [PermComparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/). That's the link to the heroku app that you can allow access to an org and have an easy interface to compare permission sets (can compare 4 at once) and find "common permissions" based on objects, system, etc.

The [github repo](https://github.com/john-brock/perm-comparator) for the app is accessible as well if you wanted to fork and focus it to meet your needs (if you were inclined to host your own app). Even if you plan to write it in apex, it might be worthwhile to explore the [code](https://github.com/john-brock/perm-comparator/blob/master/app/controllers/RetrieveData.java) to get ideas on what endpoints you could call yourself.